# My Matrix Synapse Homeserver is not working after I tried to install nginx proxy manager

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, matrix, docker-compose, matrix-synapse

[I GOT THIS ERROR WHEN I TRIED TO DOCKER-COMPOSE UP -D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxyw9.png)I followed my nginx proxy manager installation from this tutorial. And after 5th step, my Synapse HomeServer is not working.

https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/using-nginx-proxy-manager/

I am using Element client, and its not working.

I did not try anything because I am afraid I will make another problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, your docker image seems to be using Traefik as a web server and the error indicates that port 443 is already allocated.

So I don't understand why you want to use nginx, which is also a web server and will also use port 443, hence the error you're having.
Obviously there's a conflict, maybe you should look at the image creator for your needs ...

Well, you have to choose between Traefik and Nginx!